# Copy Excel formula to last row on multiple work sheets

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have a workbook which has multiple worksheets that vary in name but the content structure of each sheet remains the same. There is only one sheet name that is always constant `pie`.

I am trying to apply a formula in cell `N2` and then copy the formula down to the last active row in all the worksheets except the one named `pie`
The code I have so far is works for one loop but then i get an error *"AutoFill method of Range Class failed"*
I have used

```
Lastrow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

to determine the last row as column M is always complete.
Any help to complete this would be very much appreciated
Code i have is:

```
Sub ConcatForm()

Dim wSht As Worksheet

Lastrow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each wSht In Worksheets
    If wSht.Name <> "Pie" Then
        wSht.Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
        wSht.Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & Lastrow)
    End If
Next wSht

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Andy, please select one of these answers as the "accepted" answer (tick mark to the left of the answer). Please also upvote any answers you found useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were just one `wSht` reference away from the goal:

```
Sub ConcatForm()
    Dim wSht As Worksheet

    lastRow = Range("M" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row '<--| without explicit worksheet qualification it will reference a range in the "active" sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each wSht In Worksheets
        If wSht.Name <> "Pie" Then
            wSht.Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
            wSht.Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=wSht.Range("N2:N" & lastRow) '<--| this will reference a range in 'wSht' worksheet
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So close. So all I had to do was declare the wSht variable as the autofill destination?

Comment: Yes, exactly as the worksheet qualification of the destination range. Without that qualification the "active" sheet is assumed implicitly

Comment: @Andybrute, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes thank you @user3598756. I used this but changed it slightly to use direct formula as I can understand this more. Bit of a vba novice but I'm enjoying the journey. Thank ks to all who are helping

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Autofill` to achieve this.

1. Just apply your formulas directly to your range and **use relative references**, i.e. `K2`, rather than absolute references, i.e. `$K$2`. It will *fill* down and update the formula for you.
2. Make sure you are fully qualifying your references. For example, see where I have used `ThisWorkbook` and the update to how `lastrow` is initialized. Otherwise, Excel can get confused and throw other errors.
3. Your `lastrow` variable hasn't been dimensioned so it is an implicit `Variant`. You'd be better off dimensioning it explicitly as a `Long`.

---

```
Sub ConcatForm()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'which worksheet to get last row?
        lastrow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each wSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wSht.Name <> "Pie" Then
            wSht.Range("N2:N" & lastrow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(K2,L2,M2)"
        End If
    Next wSht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great @CallumDA and I much prefer applying the formulas direct. The only problem I have is running this script from the PERSONAL.XLSB due to the "With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'which worksheet to get last row?"  Is there a way this can be applied to any workbook?

Comment: @Andybrute, in that case, you can change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` in both places. Don't forget to upvote any useful answers and if this resolved your question please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of this answer :)

Comment: @andybrute the other option is to just remove `ThisWorkbook` which will use the implied active workbook without you needing to specify `ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score -2):

Use following sub...

```
Sub ConcatForm()
    Dim wSht As Worksheet

    Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each wSht In Worksheets
    With wSht
        If .Name <> "Pie" Then
            .Select
            .Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
            .Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & Lastrow)
        End If
    End With
    Next wSht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't promote the use of `.Select`.

Comment: Again this works fine but I prefer using the direct formula. @CallumDA Why is '.select' not good to use?

Comment: Hi @Andybrute, there's loads of articles about the use of .Select - a quick Google should reveal all! :)

Comment: I can see how this can be confusing. Thanks for advice